# Cross account access to a CodeArtifact repo

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-codeartifact

I have an IAM user in account A with admin privileges and `arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AWSCodeArtifactReadOnlyAccess` attached for good measure.

The iam user from account A has an arn of `arn:aws:iam::***:user/test-user`.

Account B has a CodeArtifact repo with an arn of `arn:aws:codeartifact:***:***:domain/test-repo`. This repo has a resource policy of

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::***:user/test-user"
            },
            "Action": "codeartifact:*",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

When running AWS CLI commands, I'm using the access keys for the IAM user from account A. The following command works:

```
$ aws codeartifact get-repository-endpoint --domain test-repo --domain-owner *** --query repositoryEndpoint --output text --repository test --format pypi
```

Results in

> `https://test-repo-***.d.codeartifact.***.amazonaws.com/pypi/test/`

This demonstrates that my resource policy is working (flipping the `Effect` to a `Deny` successful makes the above command fail).

However, the following command

```
$ aws codeartifact get-authorization-token --domain test-repo --domain-owner *** --query authorizationToken --output text
```

fails with

> An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the GetAuthorizationToken operation: User: arn:aws:iam::***:user/test-user is not authorized to perform: codeartifact:GetAuthorizationToken on resource: arn:aws:codeartifact:***:***:domain/test-repo

I believe I've followed the docs here:

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codeartifact/latest/ug/repo-policies.html#granting-read-access-to-specific-principals
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codeartifact/latest/ug/auth-and-access-control-iam-identity-based-access-control.html

I would like to accomplish this with the specified principal and would like to not assume a role as it complicates my CI/CD pipeline

Comment: Any progress on this?

Comment: @Derrops also interested if you found a solution

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I was having this same issue for a couple days, finally figured out there needs to be a policy applied to both the repository AND the codeartifact domain.

This example uses an organization based policy but any principal should work, the only other important part is the permission of `sts:GetServiceBearerToken`

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "ContributorPolicy",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": [
                "codeartifact:*",
                "sts:GetServiceBearerToken"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "aws:PrincipalOrgID": "o-xxxxxxxxxx"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

We had to do a few things:

1. AWS Account with CodeArtifact: (Domain level) > Edit/Create Policy

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::<OTHER_AWS_ACCCOUNT_ID>:root"
            },
            "Action": "codeartifact:GetAuthorizationToken",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

2. AWS Account with CodeArtifact: (Repository level) > Edit/Create Policy

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::<OTHER_AWS_ACCCOUNT_ID>:root"
            },
            "Action": [
                "codeartifact:GetRepositoryEndpoint",
                "codeartifact:ReadFromRepository"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:codeartifact:*:<CURRENT_AWS_ACCCOUNT_ID>:repository/<REPOSITORY_NAME>/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

3. AWS Account with Amplify App: (different account than 1 & 2 above) General > Service Role > Edit/Create Service Role

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "codeartifact:GetAuthorizationToken",
                "codeartifact:GetRepositoryEndpoint",
                "codeartifact:ReadFromRepository",
                "sts:GetServiceBearerToken"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

This solved our cross-account NPM package running angular app.

Answer (score 0):

As per the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codeartifact/latest/ug/auth-and-access-control-iam-identity-based-access-control.html), you will be required to add `"sts:GetServiceBearerToken"` access in your access policy as well.

> The codeartifact:GetAuthorizationToken and sts:GetServiceBearerToken permissions are required to call the GetAuthorizationToken API.

Secondly, in your user's permissions, explicitly mention the codeartifact resource in your access policy, same as you have mentioned the IAM User in the resource policy.

e.g.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "codeartifact:*"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "<insert cross account resource's ARN>"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "sts:GetServiceBearerToken",
            "Resource": "<insert cross account resource's ARN>",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "sts:AWSServiceName": "codeartifact.amazonaws.com"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: This didn't work. These permissions have already been granted per 
> I have an IAM user in account A with admin privileges and arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AWSCodeArtifactReadOnlyAccess attached for good measure.

I tried specifically calling out the arn of the resource as you suggested. No luck. You said "<insert cross account resource's IAM>"; do you mean the iam of the code artifact repo?

Comment: @brno32 Yes, I meant that

Comment: @amsh what do you mean by "resource's IAM"? Did you mean "ARN"?

Comment: @gshpychka yes, I meant ARN, thanks for correction.

Answer (score 0):

I had, in addition to the solution above, to add the permission to change the policy to the user connected to the repository environment :
Done in the IAM of the user by the user who can modify that user (in my case root)

AWSCodeArtifactAdminAccess

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "codeartifact:*"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "sts:GetServiceBearerToken",
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "sts:AWSServiceName": "codeartifact.amazonaws.com"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```