# Lambda access to Codeartifact

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-codeartifact

I have a Codeartifact repository configured with a policy that allows read access for any Principal.

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action": [
        "codeartifact:GetAuthorizationToken",
        "codeartifact:ReadFromRepository",
        "codeartifact:ListPackageVersionAssets",
        "codeartifact:GetPackageVersionAsset",
        "sts:GetServiceBearerToken"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:codeartifact:eu-west-1:123456789012:repository/libraries",
        "arn:aws:codeartifact:eu-west-1:123456789012:repository/libraries/test-repository"
    }
  ]
}
```

This is done both for Repository and Domain following the accept answer from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67911411/cross-account-access-to-a-codeartifact-repo).

Now, I want to get access to this repository from a lambda function in other account (987654321098). So, I create a Role (`my-lambda-function-role`) for the lambda function with the following policy (`my-lambda-function-policy`) attached.

```
{
  "Effect": "Allow",
  "Action": [
    "codeartifact:GetAuthorizationToken",
    "codeartifact:ReadFromRepository",
    "codeartifact:ListPackageVersionAssets",
    "codeartifact:GetPackageVersionAsset",
    "sts:GetServiceBearerToken"
  ],
  "Resource": "*"
}
```

In the lambda function I'm trying to get the authorization token to be able to download the packages:

```
client = boto3.client('codeartifact')
response = client.get_authorization_token(domain='libraries', domainOwner='123456789012')
```

But I'm getting the error:

```
An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the GetAuthorizationToken operation: User: arn:aws:sts::987654321098:assumed-role/my-lambda-function-role/my-lambda-function-role-role is not authorized to perform: codeartifact:GetAuthorizationToken on resource: arn:aws:codeartifact:eu-west-1:123456789012:domain/libraries because no identity-based policy allows the codeartifact:GetAuthorizationToken action
```

What I'm missing for accessing Codeartifact from the lambda function in a different account?